# Find the $a^3-b^2$ where $a,b$ satisfies this limit equation.

Tags: limits

Find $a^3-b^2$ where a,b satisfies:

$\lim \limits_{x\to\infty} ((x^2+1)/(x+1) - ax-b) = 0.$

I tried equating it to $0$
I.e. \begin{align}&\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} - ax-b\right)= 0 \\
& \implies \frac{x^2+1}{x+1} = ax+b \\
& \implies  x^2+1= ax^2 + ax + bx + b \end{align}
Then I compared the coefficients
Which gave
\begin{align}a&= 1,\\
a+b &= 0,\\
b &= 1, \end{align}
But if $a=b=1$ then how can $a+b =0$  am confused at this point.

Can't figure whats wrong with my steps

Comment: It's obvious that $a=1$ and the rest is also obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}$ is not a polynomial, we can't equate it directly to a linear polynomial.

However, as $x$ goes to $\infty$, it behaves as if it is linear. As you can see from the picture, though it is not a linear function, as $x$ grows bigger, it behaves almost linearly.

[image]

Since

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}=x-1+\frac{2}{x+1},$$

we have

\begin{align}\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b\right]&=\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[(1-a)x+(-1-b)+\frac{2}{x-1}\right] \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}(1-a)x+(-1-b) \end{align}

Note that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2}{x-1}=0$.

You should be able to read off the value of $a$ and $b$ from the discussion above.

Comment: Therefore lim(x->inf) ((1-a)x+(-b-1)) =0. Therefore if a= 1 then b= 1 right.

Comment: you are very close now, the value of $a$ is correct. To solve for $b$, try solving $-b-1=0$.